# Cygwin: git svn complains about bad config file

Tags: cygwin, git-svn

On Cygwin using git-svn performing remote operations such as:

- git svn rebase
- git svn dcommit
- etc.

Causes one of many strange error messages to occur regarding bad config files

```
$ git svn rebase
fatal: bad config file line 1 in /home/tj/.gitconfig
fatal: bad config file line 1 in /home/tj/.gitconfig
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

There aren't actually any unstaged changes, that error message seems to be an artifact of the config file issue:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Occasionally it complains about other lines in the same file, or about lines in .git/config

My actual git config files are very simple, and the exact same ones work fine on other machines (which are also running Cygwin). For reference:

.gitconfig:

```
[user]
        name = tj
        email = tj@example.com
```

.git/config:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        preloadindex = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://url.to/repository
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

The octo-spacing is a tab in the file, and looking at the file in vim with set list shows no strange characters muddling around.

The strangest part of all is that sometimes it just works without issue. However, after a short period of time, it continues showing the error messages. If anyone knows that the issue may be, or how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Edit:

What I've tried so far:

- Copying good config files from working machines running Cygwin
- Running rebaseall in Cygwin
- Reinstalling git-svn package

What I might try:

- Reinstalling Cygwin (would rather not)

Edit2: Success?

After fiddling around with this for a few hours, I tried removing things from the git configs one by one and seeing if it made a difference.

Removing preloadindex = true from the .git/config file seems to have resolved the issue, though it is difficult to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was indeed core.preloadindex = true, which does not play nice in cygwin.